# Click multiple buttons with Selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click multiple buttons with Selenium ChromeDriver, should be easy, I just find the buttons by class name because they all have the same class name, looping through each one and clicking.
However for some reason, if I check the len of the Buttons it is 0 it is like it's not on the page...

Here is the HTML:

**button1**

```
<span data-fieldid="9537" id="bounceRatingOrderBtn" name="bounceRatingOrderBtn" class="viewCommand viewSize1 viewCommandGreenBtn" data-columnnum="1" data-showonload="1" data-defaultvalue="" data-isrequired="0" data-personalareaviewposition="manage_area" data-ispersonalareaviewable="1" data-ajax_path="//my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?action=updateBounceListing&amp;CatID=3&amp;SubCatID=0&amp;OrderID=39605635" data-viewcommandactive="1" data-originalelementname="input" xpath="1">  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span>הקפצת מודעה</span></span>
```

**button2**

```
<span data-fieldid="9537" id="bounceRatingOrderBtn" name="bounceRatingOrderBtn" class="viewCommand viewSize1 viewCommandGreenBtn" data-columnnum="1" data-showonload="1" data-defaultvalue="" data-isrequired="0" data-personalareaviewposition="manage_area" data-ispersonalareaviewable="1" data-ajax_path="//my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?action=updateBounceListing&amp;CatID=3&amp;SubCatID=0&amp;OrderID=39605688" data-viewcommandactive="1" data-originalelementname="input" xpath="1">  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span>הקפצת מודעה</span></span>
```

**button3**

```
<span data-fieldid="9537" id="bounceRatingOrderBtn" name="bounceRatingOrderBtn" class="viewCommand viewSize1 viewCommandGreenBtn" data-columnnum="1" data-showonload="1" data-defaultvalue="" data-isrequired="0" data-personalareaviewposition="manage_area" data-ispersonalareaviewable="1" data-ajax_path="//my.yad2.co.il/newOrder/index.php?action=updateBounceListing&amp;CatID=3&amp;SubCatID=0&amp;OrderID=39594079" data-viewcommandactive="1" data-originalelementname="input" xpath="1">  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span>הקפצת מודעה</span></span>
```

**My Python code:**

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("viewCommand viewSize1 viewCommandGreenBtn"):
    print('here')
    i.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Compound classes are represented like this in CSS

```css
classOne.classTwo.classThree {
    //...
}
```

Try doing

```py
for btn in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('viewCommand.viewSize1.viewCommandGreenBtn'):
    btn.click()
```

Comment: Tried that It does not even enter the loop.., I dont know why, the only way I got it to work is by xpath

Comment: @yarinCohen Have you tried just doing `print(driver.find_elements...)` to check if it returns anything?

Comment: I checked the length of it and it's 0, I can post the full HTML code if it will help

Comment: What if you prepend a `.` to the selector? So do `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.viewCommand.viewSize1.viewCommandGreenBtn')`. Does that work?

Comment: Same result, Could it be because it is in an iframe?

Comment: @yarinCohen That's possible. You might also want to consider just getting the HTML representation using `selenium` and leave the parsing of the source to `bs4`.

Comment: I get an error message "element is not attached to the page document" I think

Comment: @yarinCohen: For `iframes` I believe you'll have to use your driver to `get` the content from the source URL. I'm not sure whether you'll really want to do this though.